# eliminar campos con checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla con varios mensajes de correo, y cada mensaje tiene un checkbox , para que al apretar un botón Eliminar que hay debajo de la tabla, se borren los marcados y se actualice la tabla.
La lista me aparece bien, pero no me borra los mensajes seleccionados.
Este es el código que tengo ahora:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>MENSAJES</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","");
            $BD="mensajes";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('mensajes.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
            echo "<h1>LISTADO DE MENSAJES DE CORREO.</h1>
                <p>Selecciona el 'asunto' de un mensaje para ver su contenido.</p>
                <p>Maraca los que deseas borrar y pulsa el botón 'Eliminar'.</p>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action=\"index.php\">";
            $_POST['Eliminar']="";
            $_POST['checkbox']="";
            $sql1='SELECT id,de,asunto,fecha FROM mensajes';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
            echo "<table border=1>
                <tr bgcolor='#FF0000'><th align='left'>De</th><th align='left'>Asunto</th><th align='left'>Fecha</th><th align='left'>Operaciones</th></tr>";
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo "<tr bgcolor='#F78181'><td>".$fila1['de']."</td><td><a href='asunto.php?id'>".$fila1['asunto']."</td><td>".$fila1['fecha']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' value='".$fila1['id']."'></td>";
            };
            echo "<tr colspan='4' bgcolor='#F78181'><td colspan='4' align='right'><input type='submit' name='Eliminar' value='Eliminar'></td></tr>
                </table></form>";
            if(isset($_POST['Eliminar'])){
                if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])&&count($_POST['checkbox'])>0){
                    $borrar=implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']);
                    $sql2="DELETE FROM mensajes WHERE id IN ('{$borrar}')";
                    $resultado2=$db->query($sql2);
                }else{
                    echo "nada";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualize tu código (lo indente mejor) teniendo en cuenta que el archivo se llama index.php y que el action del form debe llevar al mismo index.php para que pueda entrar al condicional de si existe EL `$_POST['Eliminar']`, cambialo y me dices si funciona

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MENSAJES</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
        define("USUARIO","root");
        define("CLAVE","");
        $BD="mensajes";
        $db;
        try {
          if ($BD != '') {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
          }
          else {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
          }
          if ($BD == ''){
            $sql=file_get_contents('mensajes.sql');
            $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
          }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            exit("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: {$e->getMessage()} </p>\n");
        }
        echo "<h1>LISTADO DE MENSAJES DE CORREO.</h1>
            <p>Selecciona el 'asunto' de un mensaje para ver su contenido.</p>
            <p>Maraca los que deseas borrar y pulsa el botón 'Eliminar'.</p>"

        echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action='index.php'>";
        $sql1 = 'SELECT id,de,asunto,fecha FROM mensajes';
        $resultado1 = $db->query($sql1);
        echo "<table border='1'>
          <tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>
            <th align='left'>De</th>
            <th align='left'>Asunto</th>
            <th align='left'>Fecha</th>
            <th align='left'>Operaciones</th>
          </tr>";
        while (($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) != NULL) {
            echo "<tr bgcolor='#F78181'>
              <td>{$fila1['de']}</td>
              <td>
                <a href='asunto.php?id'>{$fila1['asunto']}
              </td>
              <td>{$fila1['fecha']}</td>
              <td>
                <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='' value='{$fila1['id']}'>
              </td>";
        }
        echo "<tr colspan='4' bgcolor='#F78181'>
                <td colspan='4' align='right'>
                  <input type='submit' name='Eliminar' value='Eliminar'>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>";
        if (isset($_POST['Eliminar'])) {
          if (count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0) {
            $borrar = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
            $sql2 = "DELETE FROM mensajes WHERE id IN ('{$borrar}')";
            $resultado2 = $db->query($sql2);
          } else {
            echo "nada";
          }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo tengo, en el action del form había puesto el index con comillas dobles y una barra:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MENSAJES</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","");
            $BD="mensajes";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('mensajes.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
            echo "<h1>LISTADO DE MENSAJES DE CORREO.</h1>
                <p>Selecciona el 'asunto' de un mensaje para ver su contenido.</p>
                <p>Maraca los que deseas borrar y pulsa el botón 'Eliminar'.</p>";
            echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action='index.php'>";
            $sql1='SELECT id,de,asunto,fecha FROM mensajes';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
            echo "<table border=1>
                <tr bgcolor='#FF0000'><th align='left'>De</th><th align='left'>Asunto</th><th align='left'>Fecha</th><th align='left'>Operaciones</th></tr>";
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo "<tr bgcolor='#F78181'><td>".$fila1['de']."</td><td><a href='asunto.php?id'>".$fila1['asunto']."</td><td>".$fila1['fecha']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='' value='".$fila1['id']."'></td>";
            };
            echo "<tr colspan='4' bgcolor='#F78181'><td colspan='4' align='right'><input type='submit' name='Eliminar' value='Eliminar'></td></tr>
                </table></form>";
            if(isset($_POST['Eliminar'])){
                if($_POST['checkbox']){
                    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value){
                        $sql2="DELETE FROM mensajes WHERE id=".(int)$value;
                        $resultado2=$db->query($sql2);
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```